# Komparativ gewisser Adjektivisierungen

Tags: adjective

Betrachte man zum Beispiel folgendes Adjektiv: *blauäugig*<sup>1</sup>. Im Sinne von *Naivität* ist es total nachvollziehbar, dass dessen Komparativ *blauäugiger* ist (was ein [Wörterbuch](http://www.dict.cc/?s=blau%C3%A4ugig) bestätigt), weil die wortwörtliche Bedeutung schon verloren ging.

Anscheinend erfüllt die Bildung eines solchen Komparativs den folgenden Ablauf:

1. Gewisses Nomen (im Beispiel oben *Auge*) und dessen Adjektivisierung (-*äugig*) werden betrachtet.
2. Betrachte man anderes Adjektiv (*blau*)
3. Zusammensetzung mit der Adjektivisierung des originalen Nomens (*blauäugig*)

Dieser Ablauf übt den Eindruck, dass man eher das Nomen steigert (vielleicht ist nicht so).

**Frage**: Gibt es Adjektive der oben beschriebenen Form, bei denen diese Steigerungsform nicht gültig sein könnte oder komisch klingt?

**Beispiel:** 
Kommt der Satz

> Diese Frage ist *schwachsinniger* als die andere.

jemandem komisch vor?

---

<sup>1</sup> Ich mag das Adjektiv nicht besonders, ich fand halt kein anderes für ein schöneres Beispiel. Finde der/die LeserIn eins, bitte ersetze er/sie das ruhig in der Frage.

Comment: AFAIK wird bspw. "hochwertig" üblicherweise als "höherwertig" gesteigert, aber "hochwertiger" wird auch benutzt: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=h%C3%B6herwertig+als%2Chochwertiger+als&year_start=1850&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ch%C3%B6herwertig%20als%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chochwertiger%20als%3B%2Cc0

Comment: You might be interested into [this article on canoonet](http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Adjektiv/Komparation/Zusammen.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Allgemein

Das hängt von den Bestandteilen und der Gesamtbedeutung ab. Elena brachte das wunderschöne Beispiel `hochwertig`.

Dieses Adjektiv wird auch heute noch in zwei ähnlichen, aber leicht verschiedenen Bedeutungen verwendet.

1. *Es hat einen hohen Wert* wie *Es hat einen hohen Preis*. `wertig` oder halt `preisig` sind hier skalierbare Größe. Sie können hoch und nieder, höher und niederer, am höchsten oder am niedersten sein. Folglich ergeben sich:

   - `höherwertig` und `niederwertig`
   - `höchstwertig` und `niederstwertig`

   Das sind aber keine Steigerungen, sondern Komposita von Steigerungen und dem ungesteigerten Adjektiv `wertig`.
2. *Es hat pauschal eine gute Qualität*, weil es gut verarbeitet ist oder aus guten Materialien besteht oder aus welchen Gründen auch immer. Das `hoch` wurde hier inhaltlich mit `wertig` verschmolzen um diese neue Bedeutung zu schaffen. `hoch` ist also kein eigenständiger Teil mehr. Dieses Adjektiv `hochwertig` kann problemlos gesteigert werden:

   - `hochwertiger` (hat eine noch bessere Qualität oder mehr Qualitäten)
   - `am hochwertigsten` (hat die bessten oder die meisten Qualitäten)

### Schwachsinnig

`schwachsinnig` bedeutet heute eben nicht, dass der Sinn schwach (ausgeprägt) ist. Dann würde man `schwächersinnig` und `schwächstsinnig` sowie entgegengesetzt `starksinnig`, … bilden können, was es aber nicht gibt. Auch hier haben sich die Bestandteile des Kompositums zu einer neuen Bedeutung verschmolzen. Die Steigerung muss sich also hier wie im zweiten Fall oben auf das gesamte Kompositum beziehen

> schwachsinnig, schwachsinniger, am schwachsinnigsten

Grammatikalisch sind die Steigerungsformen so korrekt, ob man sie inhaltlich für sinnhaft hält, hängt von der genauen Definition von `schwachsinnig` ab. Als Lehrer habe ich die persönliche Erfahrung gemacht, dass Schwachsinnigkeit durchaus skalierbar und somit das Adjektiv inhaltlich steigerbar ist.

Comment: +1 - schon allein fuer den letzten Satz. Meine Beobachtung kommt aus dem Managementbereich. Allerdings bin ich nicht sicher ob es den Superlativ in der freien Wildbahn gibt. Jedes mal wenn ich dachte dass ich die schwachsinnigste Idee gesehen habe, kommt bald jemand mit einer noch schwachsinnigeren Idee daher. ;)

Comment: @PeterSchuetze Wenn man sich auf tatsächlich gestellte Fragen beschränkt, dann gibt es den Superlativ, weil die Menge bisher gestellter Fragen endlich ist. Irgendeine davon muss die schwachsinnigste sein. Wenn man die unendliche Menge denkbarer Fragen betrachtet, dann gibt es den Superlativ möglicherweise nicht.

Comment: Ich haette die Ironie-Tags hinzufuegen sollen. Natuerlich stimme ich Deiner Logic zu.